# is it possible to change display text of argparse argument name

Tags: python, argparse

using argparse i have made a command line tool, which takes below arguments,

`usage: ipush [-h] [-v] [-c] [-to [TO]] [-V] [-p PATCHES] [-d DIFF]`

from the below code..

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='ipush',
    description='Utility to push the last commit and email the color diff')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true',
    help='if enabled will spit every command and its resulting data.')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--compose', action='store_true',
    help='compose message in default git editor to be sent prefixed with diff')
parser.add_argument('-to', type=validate_address, default=os.getenv('myemail'),
    help='enter a valid email you want to send to.', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-V', '--version', action='version',
    version='%(prog)s 1.0')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--patches', type=int, default=0,
    help='total number of pathces of last commits to email')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--diff', required=False, default='HEAD^ HEAD',
    help='if present pass arguments to it as you \
    will do to git diff in inverted commas')
```

is it possible to display TO in `[-to [TO]]` PATCHES in `[-p PATCHES]` and DIFF in `[-d DIFF]` with a different text?

Comment: You can also give the `parser` a custom `usage` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as described in the [`argparse` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#metavar):

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', metavar='YYY')
>>> parser.add_argument('bar', metavar='XXX')
>>> parser.parse_args('X --foo Y'.split())
Namespace(bar='X', foo='Y')
>>> parser.print_help()
usage:  [-h] [--foo YYY] XXX

positional arguments:
 XXX

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
 --foo YYY
```

Comment: Cannot use with  `action='store_true'`:p

Comment: True, but options that take an additional argument make no sense with `store_true` action, because that would discard their argument.